# (Python) Help decoding what is happening here

Tags: python, linked-list

**This code is not mine, I am just trying to understand it!**

I need some help understanding what is happening in this `lst2link` function.

So the function starts off by creating two `ListNode`s in the variables `cur` and `dummy` and the then proceeds to build the linked list using the orginal `cur` as the head. It returns `dummy.next`. When I run this and see what is returned it appears that `dummy.next` is the head of the linked list created using `cur`. There does not appear to be anywhere indicating that `dummy.next` points to the head of the linked list created in this function? How does it know to point there?

```
class ListNode:
   def __init__(self, x):
       self.val = x
       self.next = None


def lst2link(lst):
    cur = dummy = ListNode(0)
    for e in lst:
        cur.next = ListNode(e)
        cur = cur.next
    return dummy.next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the function starts off by creating two ListNodes in the variables cur and dummy

This is not true -- it creates *one* `ListNode`, but assigns two variables to reference that same node.

As the list is built, the `cur` variable is moved down the list, so that it always points to the last node.  `dummy` is never reassigned, so it continues to point at the original (first) node, which is not considered part of the final list that is returned.

Supposing that we call this function with the input `[1, 2]`, the sequence of events looks something like this:

```
cur = dummy = ListNode(0)

# cur
# [0]
# dummy
```

```
cur.next = ListNode(1)
cur = cur.next

#        cur
# [0] -> [1]
# dummy
```

```
cur.next = ListNode(2)
cur = cur.next

#               cur
# [0] -> [1] -> [2]
# dummy
```

```
return dummy.next

#               cur
# [0] -> [1] -> [2]
# dummy   ^
#         |
#       return
```

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you for the detailed explaination!

Answer (score 0):

list2link function accepts a list of ListNode objects. It then declares two variables 'cur' and 'dummy' with a instantiated ListNode with value 0.

The function then iterates over the ListNode objects received in the list adding the first item as the 'next' or child variable of the 'cur' variable.

It then sets the cur variable to the just added  child node. It repeats this adding the next item in  the previous node as its child. Resulting in a tree like structure with every node having one child.

Although this code allows no way to access the parent node, so even though it has added it as a child, it can never go back up the list.

As well the returned value 'dummy.next' is only set in the objects init method to None, so this will only ever return None.